# Running Python Scripts on Azure SQL Databases using Elastic Job Agent

Tags: python, sql-server, etl, xp-cmdshell

In the past, my go-to approach for ETL jobs has been writing Python scripts (as Python, unlike many other dedicated ETL tools, brings the full power, rich libraries and customisability a programming language), and then execute these scripts using `exec xp_cmdshell` from within SQL Stored Procedure by:

`EXEC xp_cmdshell 'C:/.../python.exe C:\...\script.py';`

which was then scheduled via SQL Server Agent. However, this approach requires dedicated managed SQL Server machine on which Python can be installed, which is a different species from the Azure SQL Database (my employer moved to cloud). Since there is no alternative to `exec xp_cmdshell` on Azure SQL Database, I am wondering if there is a work around.

I know there is Elastic Job Agent on Azure SQL Database, so we can schedule Stored Procedures, but I cannot figure out about the Python part. I have Googled extensively and any help would be appreciated.

P.S. I know Python scripts can be run via Azure Data Factory but that is an additional cost.

Comment: there are multiple approaches like Azure functions, Azure automation runbooks etc to run python code in Azure

Comment: were you able to find the answer @ImranAli? I am looking to do the same.